# Get a module not found when spinning up dev sever after adding new app to Django

Tags: python, django

I have created one app in Django successfully and linked it to the appropriate URLS and views but when I try to setup a second app, the dev server kicks back a error... not sure how to fix this.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'about'
```

I have double checked the code many times to ensure the second app is written the same as the first app but it seems to be the same and the dev server still wont spin up.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.about, name="About"),
]

import django.shortcuts


def about(request):
return django.shortcuts.render(request, "about.html")

urlpatterns = (
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^index/', include('index.urls')),
    url(r'^about/', include('about.urls')),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
urlpatterns = (
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^index/', views.index),
    url(r'^about/', views.about)
```

try this

Comment: After the change > "Views not defined"?

Comment: make sure you define your view in views.py file and app name in setting installed app.